# How can I execute a piece of selected lines on terminal with a mapped command?

Tags: vimscript

I've created the following script on my `vimrc` file:

```
function! ExecuteOnTerminal() 
    if (&ft=='javascript')
        :%terminal node
    elseif (&ft=='sh')
        :%terminal bash
    elseif (&ft=='python')
        :%terminal python3
    endif
endfunction

map <F6> :silent call ExecuteOnTerminal()<CR>
```

It works fine... It detects the type of the file that I'm editing and when I press F6 and I'm in Normal mode it will execute the current file on a splited terminal window. However, I'd like to go beyond this functionality and detect if I currently have selected lines on Vim. if I do, I'd like to execute only the current selected lines. If I don't, I'd like to execute the entire file (executing the entire file is the current behavior).

When I try to press F6 with this script I receive the error `No range allowed`. Is there any way of detecting if I'm in visual mode and executing a different command for it? Or would it be better creating a new command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "No range allowed" is due to `:silent` that never accepts line range, obviously. If you need to silent your command while still accepting line range you have to employ some alternative. Maybe `:h map-silent`, or `:h map-cmd`, etc.etc.
2. As your function doesn't have the `range` keyword it will be executed once per each line in a given range that is probably not what you want. Hence, you'd better to add `range` to it and to process it accordingly. See `:h :func-range`, `:h :call`, `:h function-range-example` and all such.

Yet another alternative is to drop line range forcefully (by `:h c_CTRL-U` or `:h map-cmd`) and then to get line numbers with bookmarks `'<` and `'>` (for Visual-mode mapping) or `line(".")` and `:h v:count` (for Normal-mode mapping).